# Is there a proper way to "authenticate after validation" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The problem is that both `FormRequest::authorize` and `resource policy` is called before the validation of FormRequest.

Szenario:

I want to authenticate the create of a category in a specific department.
The payload of the request contains the `label` and the `department_id`.

Not every user is allowed to create categories. It's restricted to the write permission of its department.
With the background that validation follows the authentication I get either:

- `ModelNotFoundException` if the `department_id` is not valid (I need to get it to check the write permission).

or:

- `Unauthorized` if I skip Department::find or catch the exception when Policy::create is called (since the actual department permission check fails)

My current solution is to create a createCategoryValidator in my policy and throw an ValidationException when it fails.
It feels wrong, I would like to know if there is a proper solution for this scenario?